# Using Boost with Makefile/Missing Separator

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

I am brand new to make files and `Boost`, and I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) tutorial, specifically Makefile4.

I only have two source files, namely `S1.cpp`, where `main.cpp` is located, and `GaussQuadrature.h`.  Now, `GaussQuadrature.h` also uses a `Boost` file, so (as far as I know) I must tell the compiler where `Boost` is located, which is up two directories from where my source files are.  My makefile is

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-o2 -std=c++0x
DEPS = GaussQuadrature.h
OBJ = S1.o

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
     $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

S1: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) S1.o -o S1 -I ../../boost_1_55_0
```

When I run the make command I get the error

```
makeS1:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I've read this is most commonly due to missing tabs for the command (and it's interesting that when I hit 'tab' that the two commands are indented differently above), but even when I change those to

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
\t$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

S1: $(OBJ)
\t$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) S1.o -o S1 -I ../../boost_1_55_0
```

I get the same error.

Other than fixing this error, what is proper way to include the `Boost` directory in a makefile, or is there a way around including it altogether?  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your editor doesn't uses real tab characters.

Comment: Makefile *needs* real tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Boost. Makefiles require tabs

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq22_17.html

> Unlike most other DOS Make programs which accept any whitespace character at the beginning of a command in a rule, GNU Make insists that every such line begins with a TAB. (Most other Unix Make programs also require TABs, and the Posix standard requires it as well.) Make sure that the line whose number is printed in the error message (in this case, line 10) begins with a TAB.

Comment: I'm using emacs, what is the proper TAB for that?

Comment: That should be automatic if emacs is in "Makefile-mode", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146621/insert-tab-instead-of-spaces

Comment: Cool the C-q TAB worked, but how do I enter "Makefile-mode"?  My makefile doesn't have an extension, so is there a way to tell emacs to enter this mode?

Comment: Emacs checks the entire filename, not just the extension, and will automatically use makefile mode for `Makefile`, `makefile`, and any file ending in `.mk` (IIRC).