# Configure TAB key to insert spaces in .lisp, .c files, etc. in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am a beginning Emacs user. I am trying to set up Emacs to simply add 2 spaces when I hit `TAB`. [If possible, I would like to have auto-indentation within Lisp files as well, but if it's not possible to have this coexist with manual tabbing, I would prefer manual tabbing.]

Currently, in "plainly" named files, `TAB` inserts 2 spaces as expected. However, in files that have an extension `.c`, `.lisp`, `.java`, etc., that Emacs apparently recognizes, pressing `TAB` currently does nothing.

Here is the full content of my current `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~")
(setf inhibit-startup-screen t)
(load (expand-file-name "~/.quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
(global-font-lock-mode 0)
(require 'pbcopy)
(turn-on-pbcopy)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
```

[Currently, auto-indentation is working in `.lisp` and `.emacs` files.]

What can I do to make Emacs allow me to `TAB` manually in any type of file, with or without Lisp auto-indentation for Lisp files? Any info would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200174/emacs-insert-true-tabs-by-default) and reading about `global-set-key` [here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_tabs_space_indentation_setup.html), I tried adding

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

to my `.emacs` and that worked!

[ Side note - for some reason, the more standard

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

did **not** work. I am on MacOS 13.0. ]

Comment: `(kbd "TAB")` returns a literal tab character; `(kbd "<tab>")` returns the keycode for the tab key, `[tab]`

Comment: Your OS version is probably of secondary importance, but which Emacs build and version you are running could be quite significant.